# Comparison between two integers in GLSL

Tags: glsl

I want to build a fragment shader, and I realized that the comparison between two int in glsl 1.5.0 will return always false. I am using integers as an enumeration in a method parameter. This is the problem in a simple way and this code has the same result.

```c
void main(){
    int x = 5;
    #if(x == 5)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
    #else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    #endif
}
```

I tried this code and the condition `x == int(2)` will return always true!

```c
void main(){
    int x = 5;
    #if(x == int(2))
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
    #else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    #endif
}
```

So, what should I do to compare two integers in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#if`, `#else` and `#endif` are  preprocessor statements. But `int x = 5;` is a local variable. The preprocessor processes the source string, it is part of the comoilation process, but it is done before the actual compilation. The variable `x` has no meaning for the preprocessor.

A `x` for the preprocessor can be defines a follow:

```c
#define x 5

#if(x == 5)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
#else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
#endif
```

But a glsl `if` statement start with the keyword `if` followed by a bool-expression and a statement. Optional followed by the keyword `else` and another statement:

```c
int x = 5;
if (x == 5)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
}
else
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

In this case the curly braces can be skipped, because in each case there is only a single statement.

Note, a ternary operator can be used, too:

```c
gl_FragColor = x==5 ? vec4(1.0) : vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

This all can be read in the [OpenGL Shading Language 1.50 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf) in detail. The preprocessor is explained in chapter "3.3 Preprocessor", the `if` statement is specified in chapter "6.2 Selection" and and the Ternary operator in chapter "5.8 Assignments"